# Can't access child in JSON (child is an integer)

Tags: json, node.js

This is the JSON file...

```
{

        tm: {
            1: {

                pl: {
                    1: {

                        name: "R. Miniotas"

                    },
                    2: {

                        name: "T. Delininkaitis"

                    },
                    3: {

                        name: "V. Cizauskas"

                    },
                    4: {

                        name: "T. Klimavicius"

                    },
                    5: {

                        name: "V. Lipkevicius"

                    }
                }
```

This is my code so far...

```
var http = require('http');

var url = 'http://www.fibalivestats.com/data/586746/data.json';

http.get(url, function(res){
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        var resp = JSON.parse(body);
        var team = resp.tm
        console.log("Got a response: ", team);
    });
}).on('error', function(e){
      console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});
```

How am I able to get the child which is an integer. In this case it is 1. And after getting all children data from pl. I am not sure if this is the right or reasonable approach to fetch JSON with Node.js but here I am.

Comment: `data.tm["1"].pl["1"]` ?

Comment: @wostex Well done! Thank you! Problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

JSON provided is not well formed as all the keys should have been strings whiles values can be of different types like string/integer/double etc.

You can use online JSON editor (like http://jsonparseronline.com/) to check if it is well formed.

Attaching the screen shot for reference on how correct JSON data will look like [image]